# Gauss-Seidel: I can't get diagonally dominant equations

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus

I've got the question:

Use the Gauss-Seidel method to solve:

$8x_1 - 16x_2 = 6$

$4x_1 + 8x_2 = 0$

I know that the equations have to be diagonally dominant, but I can't see how to determine this. I would change the system above to be diagonally dominant.

No matter which way round I have the equations, I just seem to be in an endless loop, so no divergence; but I don't get two results in a row to assume an answer.

Any ideas/hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add the second equation to the first?